# How to check and remove the extra changes from FTP server which are created from c-panel directly, but not pushed from bitbucket pipeline

Tags: php, continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I have configured the Bitbucket Pipeline and whenever i am committing any thing on master branch its automatically auto deploy to the FTP Server.
Now the Problem is that i am adding a file manually in FTP server, and pushing new commit in repository, Now it should verify that, the server is synced until the last pushed files and delete all extra files and folders which are not in the last commit and update with new commit.

what changes should i make into the script to verify that on each auto deployment, it should verify first that no changes has been in server directly, all changes are pushed from bitbucket.

```
image: php:7.1.29

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
       script:
         - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp:$address
```

In short, check that the ftp server has all the changes synced until the last push from bitbucket.

If i will create a file.txt in server manually from c-panel then it will remove it automatically.

Comment: can you check, i hope it is more clear now?